# Стилизация ползунка. Не работает JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, range

```js
$(function() {
  var r = $('input');
  r.on('mouseenter', function() {
    var p = r.val();
    r.on('click', function() {
      p = r.val();
      bg(p);
    });
    r.on('mousemove', function() {
      p = r.val();
      bg(p);
    });
  });

  function bg(n) {
    r.css({
      'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(left ,#f22 0%,#f22 ' + n + '%,#fff ' + n + '%, #fff 100%)'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 3px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f22 0%, #f22 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 100%);
  box-shadow: inset #ebb 0 0 5px;
  outline: none;
  transition: .1s;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #f22;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .1s;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover,
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50">
</div>
```

Comment: Не дописал. Почему-то не работает код, ни в ФИДДЛЕ, он не понимает что за скрипт, ни в реальности. Ползунок двигается, ошибок нет, цвет не меняется.

Comment: У меня код не выполняется :)
Но дело не в этом, я только что разобрался сам, т.к. input много на странице, скрипт не понимал че делать, я указал в переменной input[type="range"], чтобы указать к какому конкретно инпуту я обращаюсь и всё заработало :)