# не работает событие change для input type=range для измененного слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

вот мой код CSS для `input type=range`

```
   input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0;
  background: #435063;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 55px;
  width: 43px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background: url(img/range_thumb.png);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

пытаюсь вызвать метод `change` на него:

```
 $('input').change(function() {
console.log('Change: ' + $(this).val())
   alert('asdasd');});
```

и ничего не получаю, ни ошибок, ни Алерта, ничего.

Но если отключить стили, то все начинает работать, в чем проблема?

Comment: указанных проблем с Вашим кодом не наблюдается https://jsfiddle.net/8o2bwe4c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у автора [данного вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/697499/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-js) примерно такая же проблема, но он говорит, что у него много `input'ов`, но у меня один и чем вызвана такая проблема, непонятно.

и Я решил попробовать его решение:

Обращаться к слайдеру не через его id/input, а путем добавления переменной в которой лежит объект `input[type="range"]`. И тогда данный скрипт будет работать

```
let slider = $('input[type="range"]');
slider.change(function() {
console.log('Change: ' + $(this).val())
;});
```

Так же проблема заключается в `-webkit-appearance: none;`
если закоменьтить данную строку, то проблема пропадет, но соответственно, тогда слайдер нельзя будет настроить по своему

Comment: Разница в том, что здесь указан тип `input` (`input[type="range"]`), возможно и у Вас на странице несколько input`ов

Comment: @Alex разница между чем и чем? Но Я в своем ответе указал, что у меня на странице только один `input`

Comment: между $('input') и $('input[type="range"]'). `$('input[type="range"]').change{..}` должен работать без присвоения к переменной.

Comment: пожалуйста отметьте Ваш ответ решением(галка слева от текста ответа). это будет означать, что Ваш вопрос имеет решение.